# Highchart legends,label are not responsive to mobile mode and it looks too smaller

Tags: highcharts, responsive

I am using highchart in react. It looks good in desktop view where as it looks too smaller in mobile devices. how can we make this responsive to make it look better in mobile devices.

Container height is set to 100% then chart appears in full screen but still font and labels are looks smaller.

[image: container set to 100% height]

[image]

Comment: Try to apply the `responsive` rules and options to increase the size of the fonts for smaller screens. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't make any difference. Basically chart should be responsive and looks good in mobile. I have used the below one in my app but it looks smaller. But where as it appears fine in sandbox in responsive.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-zhuvp?file=/demo.jsx

Comment: If it looks fine in the sandbox it means that something in your app has an impact for the chart container, like some CSS options. I am afraid that I cannot say more without reproduction of the issue.

Comment: Thank you ! I have fixed this. Its my bad I have missed the body tag in index.html in REACT

Answer (score 0):

When we use the highchart in REACT then index.html should have body tag with root div.